# Python: find string in file

Tags: python, regex, find

I have the following in my python script..

```
hostIP = sys.argv[1]
hostsFileLoc = "hosts.txt"

if not hostIP in open(hostsFileLoc).read():
    # Script to add if the string is not in file
else:
    # Print message
```

The only problem with this is that it is not an exact match, for example...

If my file contains:

```
192.168.0.111
```

And my hostIP is:

```
192.168.0.11
```

Then it will find it as a match. I thought I might be able to do this with regex, as there will always be a space `("\s+")` or a comma `("\,")` so I thought I could use something like

```
test = re.compile("^" + hostIP + "[\s\,]*")
```

and use test as my search, but this obviously does not work. I've tried to find some documentation on this but to no avail. Has anyone a suggestion on how I can use a variable with regex to have a more specific search.

Thanks

MHibbin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can split your text file by delimiters (whitespace for example) and then find string in the list:

```
if not hostIP in open(hostsFileLoc).read().split():
    # Script to add if the string is not in file
else:
    # Print message
```

Put your delimiter into *split()* if you use other than whitespaces

Answer (score 3):

The only reason it doesn't work is that you use `*` in `"[\s\,]*"`, which means "space or comma **zero or more** times". Thus it will match against `'192.168.0.111'` because it has zero spaces after `11`. Change `*` to `+` ("one or more times") and it should work.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I thought "+" would mean that it would need at least one whitespace AND one comma... wasn't thinking correctly.

However I have gone withe split method in the other answer as that was posted first and it worked for my needs. 

I will bare this in mind though, thanks for the response.